# Java Enum constructors private?

Tags: java, constructor, enums, private

I believe enum constructors in Java are meant to be private but I've recently switched over to IntelliJ and it says that the private keyword is redundant when I add it to the constructor.

Picture:

http://puu.sh/nYbwp/1c37312777.png

Does Java just automatically make them private or something?

Answer (score 1):

yes. `Enum` constructor is `private` by design.

And it is not the only example of access modifier's redundancy in Java - all interface methods are public and `public` modifier for them is not necessary too